# PostGIS extension not available in Postgresql list

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have installed Postgresql 9.2 from graphical installer in Ubuntu 13.10 and Install PostGIS 2.0.3 through StackBuilder. All things went smooth. But it is not possible to create PostGIS database as there is no extension present in Extension. As far I know two more extension is needed to be there named 'postgis' and 'postgis_topology'. I have tried

`CREATE EXTENSION postgis`

but it returns there is no postgis.control file within the extension folder. What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The postgresql apt-repository has postgis now, and I put together some instructions for pulling from this to install postgresql 9.3 and postgis 2.1 (if that version of postgis will work for you).

[View the instructions here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxh7puyDgHHoRG9MajJNNVVHSHM/edit?usp=sharing), and let me know if they work for you!

I would steer clear of enterpriseDB especially for Ubuntu / Linux. They have told me on support forums that they are not really supporting postgis on Linux properly.

Answer (score 1):

As you installed postgresql and postgis from different sources, postgresql from the ubuntu repos and postgis, from enterprisedb stackbuilder tool, the paths where the tools are looking for the binaries and the configuration files are different. Ubuntu uses /usr/lib to install postgresql but stackbuilder uses /opt.

The easiest solution is install both from the same source.

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```